# Groupby, transpose and append in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

> [image]

Each user has 10 records. Now, I want to create a dataframe which looks like this:

```
userid  name1  name2  ... name10
```

which means I need to invert every 10 records of the column `name` and append to a new dataframe.

So, how do it do it? Is there any way I can do it in Pandas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`groupby('userid')` then `reset_index` within each group to enumerate consistently across groups. Then `unstack` to get columns.

```
df.groupby('userid')['name'].apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack()
```

#### Demonstration

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [123, 'abc'],
        [123, 'abc'],
        [456, 'def'],
        [123, 'abc'],
        [123, 'abc'],
        [456, 'def'],
        [456, 'def'],
        [456, 'def'],
    ], columns=['userid', 'name'])

df.sort_values('userid').groupby('userid')['name'].apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack()
```

[image]

if you don't want the `userid` as the index, add `reset_index` to the end.

```
df.sort_values('userid').groupby('userid')['name'].apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack().reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: You Sir, is my hero. Thanks for explaining too :)

Comment: Possible to include how to collapse the extra `userid` row?  I vaguely remember that there's a way to do it. (Can't remember unfortunately :()

Answer (score 5):

You may also be interested in [*pandas.DataFrame.pivot*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

See this example dataframe:

```
df
    userid  name  values
0   123     A     1    
1   123     B     2    
2   123     C     3    
3   456     A     4    
4   456     B     5    
5   456     C     6
```

using *df.pivot*

```
df.pivot(index='userid', columns='name', values='values')
name  A   B   C
userid
123  1   2   3
456  4   5   6
```