# Groupby, pivot and concatenate in Pandas, breaking by date?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [123, 'abc', '121'],
        [123, 'abc', '121'],
        [456, 'def', '121'],
        [123, 'abc', '122'],
        [123, 'abc', '122'],
        [456, 'def', '145'],
        [456, 'def', '145'],
        [456, 'def', '121'],
    ], columns=['userid', 'name', 'dt'])
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38369424/4993513), I have managed to transpose it.

So, the desired df would be:

```
userid1_date1  name_1   name_2  ...   name_n
userid1_date2  name_1   name_2  ...   name_n
userid2        name_1   name_2  ...   name_n
userid3_date1  name_1   name_2  ...   name_n
```

**But, I want to seperate the rows depending on the date.  For example, is a user `123` has data in two days, then the rows should be seperate for each day's api events.**

I wouldn't really be needing the `userid` after the transformation, so you can use it anyway.

My plan was:

> - Group the df w.r.t the `dt` column
> - Pivot all the groups such that each looks like this:
>     `userid1_date1  name_1   name_2  ...   name_n`
> - Now, concatenate the pivoted data

But, I have no clue how to do this in pandas!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def tweak(df):
    return df.reset_index().name

df.set_index('userid').groupby(level=0).apply(tweak)
```

---

#### Demonstration

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a'], [1, 'c'], [1, 'c'], [1, 'd'], [1, 'e'],
                   [1, 'a'], [1, 'c'], [1, 'c'], [1, 'd'], [1, 'e'],
                   [2, 'a'], [2, 'a'], [2, 'c'], [2, 'd'], [2, 'e'],
                   [2, 'a'], [2, 'a'], [2, 'c'], [2, 'd'], [2, 'e'],
    ], columns=['userid', 'name'])

def tweak(df):
    return df.reset_index().name

df.set_index('userid').groupby(level=0).apply(tweak)
```

[image]

Comment: Wait. You forgot to `.unstack()` it.  It works now. But, how does this seperate the user data by `dt`?  The df looks similar to the one here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38369722/4993513